# Changing Loss Functions in R (LM/GLM)

Tags: r, linear-regression, loss-function, mse

How can I provide MAPE or MAE instead of RMSE as loss function in GLM or LM in R? 
Would like to see any good reason why there is no option to provide a custom loss function to LM algorithms in R

Comment: @RuiBarradas not a helpful comment is it?!

Comment: @cs0815 Probably not, this [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/178492/which-optimization-algorithm-is-used-in-glm-function-in-r) question seems to be closer to what the OP wants.